# How to remove highlight border color of on select primeng component

Tags: css, angular, input, primeng, styling

[See the Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yL27.png)
I am using the primeng component in my application it has css class p-component. Whenever I click on any field whether it is button or input or any other field It got highlited with blue color border. I don't need that So I tried to use outline:none but it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following CSS to remove auto highlited blue color

```
input:focus {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be good if you can post your code so that we can get a 100% correct answer to you. However, looking at [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/)'s website it seems as though the `.p-inputtext:enabled:focus` selector is setting the following

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem #BFDBFE;
border-color: #3B82F6;
```

So add a rule to your own css below the linked PrimeNG css file with the following rule

```
.p-inputtext:enabled:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    border-color: initial;
}
```

I can check this for you if you post up your code, though.

Comment: Adding css with focus works. Thanks